# Parallel.Foreach while dealing with class Collection<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to convert some existing code to Parallel.Foreach, but i am new to this Multi-threading programming and I tried to modify the code but it shows some unexpected behaviors. Each time something gets wrong. I have read about `locking` mechanism to implement but i don't know how and where to add `lock` statements. I am also not sure if the `OrganizationRequestCollection` is thread safe or not.

```
public void ImportDataToCRM(List<Invoice> invoicesList, List<InvoiceLine> invoiceLinesList)
{
  var organizationRequestCollection = new OrganizationRequestCollection();

   foreach (Invoice invoice in invoicesList) //Need to convert this to Parallel.ForEach
   {
      Entity invoiceEntity = EntityMapper.GetEntity<Invoice>(invoice);
      List<InvoiceLine> relatedLines = invoiceLinesList.Where(x => x.InternalId.Equals(invoice.InternalId) && x.DocumentNumber.Equals(invoice.DocumentNumber)).ToList();
      if (relatedLines != null && relatedLines.Count > 0)
      {
           EntityCollection invoiceLineEntityCollection = new EntityCollection();
           foreach (var invoiceLine in relatedLines ) //should this be converted to Parallel.Foreach??
           {
             Entity invoiceLineEntity = EntityMapper.GetEntity<InvoiceLine>(invoiceLine);
             //Lock here ??
             invoiceLineEntityCollection.Entities.Add(invoiceLineEntity);
           }
          //Lock here ??
          invoiceEntity.RelatedEntities.Add(new Relationship("invoice_details"), invoiceLineEntityCollection);
      }
     //Lock here ??
     organizationRequestCollection.Add(new CreateRequest()
                    {
                        Target = invoiceEntity
                    });
   }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.organizationrequestcollection.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection.aspx

Comment: To avoid the need for locking `organizationRequestCollection`, consider using `invoicesList.AsParallel().Select(z => { your code here, ultimately returning the `CreateRequest`).ToList()` and then call `organizationRequestCollection.AddRange` (if that type has that method).

Comment: _Also, `relatedLines != null` will **never** be `true`._

Answer (score 0):

1st - you do not need `ToList()` call while assigning to `List<InvoiceLine> relatedLines =`

2nd - it's hard to deduct just from the code, but if there is a chance that 
different  `Entity invoiceEntity = EntityMapper.GetEntity<Invoice>(invoice);` will return *same* `invoiceEntity`, you definitely need to lock on `invoiceEntity.RelatedEntities.Add(..)`. 
On the other hand, if it is guaranteed, by design, of your program that it will never happen, do not use `lock()`.

3rd - what about `organizationRequestCollection`: it is initialized *outside* of hypothetical parallel-for, but used *inside* of it to `Add(..)`, so, yes, with this design, you need to `lock()` there.